# Sorting hash function and Compile error

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

I used this method to sorting my hash function. When I compile the program, these errors appear:

```
Note: Retriever.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

My `hashMap<String, Double>`

```
private static Map sortByComparator(Map unsortMap) {

    List list = new LinkedList(unsortMap.entrySet());

    // sort list based on comparator
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
                    .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
        }
    });

    // put sorted list into map again
    Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Comment: `"the problem is when I want compile the program , these commands appear."` -- huh? This is very cryptic. What commands? What are "commands" exactly? What do you mean by "commands appear"? If you're getting errors, please post the error messages themselves and indicate by code comment the line(s) of code causing the error.

Comment: S/he means 'errors' not 'commands'. I've fixed the question.

Comment: seems pretty straight forward "Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked".  following the instructions should get you your answers.

Comment: I have compiled with xlint but I have not understand what are the error, because I used these cod as it is.

Comment: He actually means warnings, not errors. -Xlint:unchecked is terrible advice. Rather than suppressing all warnings you should understand what they are and suppress selectively with @SuppressWarnings only when there is no alternative. What the poster is trying to do is understand the warning so this is a good question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The bottom line though is if you are asking about problems with your code's compilation or execution and you see error messages, you should always post the messages here, since only a few of us are mind readers. I haven't reached that level yet, hence my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a compiler warning because you are ignoring the generics and using "raw" types. Ypu need to specify the generics as follows:

```
private static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByComparator(Map<K, V> unsortMap) {

    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(unsortMap.entrySet());

    //sort list based on comparator
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
         public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
           return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
         }
    });

    //put sorted list into map again
    Map<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
         Map.Entry<K, V> entry = it.next();
         sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

What's going on here, is that by specifying the generic types you're telling the compiler what types of objects these collections contain. Because of this I've been able to eliminate all the casts in the comparator and second loop. This makes the method actually type safe and checkable by the compiler.

What the compiler is telling you with the warning is that because you're using raw types and casting it can't check the accuracy of your typing. The other option is to simply suppress this warning using @SuppressWarnings but it's better to actually make the method type safe.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at the Oracle Documentation on how to use the Collections Framework.
You can use raw types, but that way you are loosing features that were introduced in Java 5 to improve code quality and productivity.

If you are new on the Collections Framework, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html. It`s a good source for understanding how it works.

As you are saying you "compiled" the program, i assume you`re not using an IDE like Eclipse to help you. I recommend you use Eclipse to help you creating your projects. It will help you with these compiler errors/warnings. Thus, it will give you some tips while you are coding, like errors, warnings and so on.

Take a look at http://www.eclipse.org/.